# vuetify changing font colors of data-table items-per-page

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am struggling to find ways to change font-colors in data-table. I found ways to change color of headers and rows, but now I need to change the color of rows-per-page count selecter box (it is filled with black font, but selector box is white and fonts are black) and also < > arrow bars for page spans are left black but I want them white

```
<template>
  <div class="container fill">
    <BootstrapNavBar></BootstrapNavBar>
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :items-per-page="5"
      class="mytable red yellow--text"
    ></v-data-table>

 
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import BootstrapNavBar from "./BootstrapNavBar.vue";
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  components: {
    BootstrapNavBar,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      itemsPerPage: 5,
      headers: [
        {
          text: "Dessert (100g serving)",
          align: "start",
          sortable: false,
          value: "name",
          class: "white--text",
        },
        { text: "Calories", value: "calories", class: "white--text" },
        { text: "Fat (g)", value: "fat", class: "white--text" },
        { text: "Carbs (g)", value: "carbs", class: "white--text" },
        { text: "Protein (g)", value: "protein", class: "white--text" },
        { text: "Iron (%)", value: "iron", class: "white--text" },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: "Frozen Yogurt",
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: "1%",
        },
      ],
      balances: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {},
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.fill {
  color: #e5e6e7;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


.theme--light.v-data-table {
  background-color: #282c30 !important;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
}


</style>
```

Red parts trying to make white font
[image: red parts trying to change]

Selector box when clicked it is black fonts over white, and selected part is all white. I need here black background, and white fonts, selected one could be another color
[image]

also why is my data-table, grayish color. Is it possible to align it with the background fill color.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want the data table in dark color including the dropdown and the respected fonts, icons, and dropdown items' text to be in contrast (white) color.

By following these two tricks you can achieve this-

1. You don't need to use a manual CSS to make the table dark and its content to be white, **use a dark prop instead. The dark prop will treat the table as dark mode, which will auto-change the font and icon colors to white.**
2. Dark mode will not change the selection box's background color. So to do that, you need to use manual CSS like this-

```
.v-sheet.v-list {
  // this is the dark mode's background color
  background: #1E1E1E !important;
}
.v-list-item:not(.v-list-item--active):not(.v-list-item--disabled) {
  // list items that are not selected
  color: white !important;
}
```

Here is a working demo-

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [{
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
          class: 'white--text',
        },
        {
          text: 'Calories',
          value: 'calories',
          class: 'white--text'
        },
        {
          text: 'Fat (g)',
          value: 'fat',
          class: 'white--text'
        },
        {
          text: 'Carbs (g)',
          value: 'carbs',
          class: 'white--text'
        },
        {
          text: 'Protein (g)',
          value: 'protein',
          class: 'white--text'
        },
        {
          text: 'Iron (%)',
          value: 'iron',
          class: 'white--text'
        },
      ],
      desserts: [{
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: 7,
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: 8,
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: 16,
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: 0,
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

```css
.v-sheet.v-list {
  background: #1E1E1E !important;
}
.v-list-item:not(.v-list-item--active):not(.v-list-item--disabled) {
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
</script>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div class="container fill">
      <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="desserts"
        :items-per-page="5"
        class="elevation-1"
        dark
        ></v-data-table>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: does this also work with vuetify2

Comment: I cannot get it running on vuetify2

Comment: I think my issue is items-per-page is getting stuck in light theme mode?

Comment: Hey, this demo is also of Vuetify 2, you can see the version in the CDN links. And, I didn't understand your last comment.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to play around with the classes mapped to the footer elements and then update the styles using custom CSS. Something like this **:**

```
i.mdi-chevron-left, i.mdi-chevron-right, i.mdi-menu-down {
  color: white !important;
}

.v-select__selections {
  color: white !important;
}
```

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
          class: 'success--text title',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

```css
.theme--light.v-data-table {
  background-color: #282c30 !important;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
}

i.mdi-chevron-left, i.mdi-chevron-right, i.mdi-menu-down {
  color: white !important;
}

.v-select__selections {
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.1.5/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.1.5/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :items-per-page="5"
      class="elevation-1"
    ></v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: this doesnt work